# How to add a message to the repeated field?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have `repeated command sendCommand = 1;` in my proto file. I'm filling command in a loop (command is message, in turn). How can I make sure that the command is added to sendCommand on each iteration of the loop? Perhaps I don't quite understand how protobuf works, since I'm new to it.

```
ar_post = request.POST
sendCommand = my_proto_pb2.sendCommand()
for i in range(len(ar_post.getlist('param1'))):
    command = sendCommand.command()
    command.param1 = ar_post.getlist('param1')[i]
    command.param2 = ar_post.getlist('param2')[i]
    command.param3 = ar_post.getlist('param3')[i]
    sendCommand.append(command)
print(sendCommand.SerializeToString().hex())
```

I tried using append() method and CopyFrom() method but I get 'invalid attribute'

Comment: You would use `.add()` on the parent object's repeated field, this will append a new message and return a mutable object that you can populate. https://protobuf.dev/reference/python/python-generated/#repeated-message-fields

Comment: @CoryKramer it should look like this sendCommand.add() = command ?

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was, I had to add messages like this `sendCommand.sendCommand.append(command)`. I was simply accessing the higher level element rather than the repeated field itself.